# How to detect height of black bar on Moto 360?

Tags: wear-os, moto-360

I'm developing an Android Wear app and content on the very bottom of the screen is cropped because of the black bar.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naf_WbtFAlY) says that we should get the height of the bar like this:

```
@Override
public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
   int barHeight = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
}
```

but in reality barHeight is always 0.

Right now I'm hacking it with

```
if (Build.MODEL.equals("Moto 360")) {

}
```

but that's not very future-proof. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I use the window insets to determine the "chin" height in an Activity of a Wear app and in a watch face engine, so it does work. I've tested on a Moto 360. This is an extract from an Activity:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            stub.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                @Override
                public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                    int chinHeight = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                    // chinHeight = 30;
                    return insets;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, it seems you need to set the listener in the onLayoutInflated method, I was calling it on GridViewPager instance.